# Centering div with @media

Tags: html, css, media-queries, centering

making a website which I want to be scalable for mobile devices. I can't figure out how to make this work, even though I tried a lot of things.

Here is my code:

```html
<div class="vertical-white">


<div class="content-container">

    <div class="horizontal-3">
      <div class="kamer-foto">
        1
      </div>

      <div class="kamer-text">
        <a href="#" class="button-room">Lees meer</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="horizontal-3">
      <div class="kamer-foto">
        2
      </div>

      <div class="kamer-text">
        <a href="#" class="button-room">Lees meer</a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="horizontal-3">
      <div class="kamer-foto">
        3
      </div>

      <div class="kamer-text">
        <a href="#" class="button-room">Lees meer</a>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

And then here is my CSS:

```css
.vertical-white {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: white;
}

.content-container {
  overflow: auto;
  width: 66%;
  max-width: 980px;
  min-width: 720px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 28, 44, 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.horizontal-3 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-top: 5%;
  margin-bottom: 5%;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: rgba(5, 100, 20, 0.3);
  margin-left: 4%;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .horizontal-3 {
    width: 250px;
    float: none;
    margin-left: 0 auto;
    margin-right: 0 auto;
  }
  .content-container {
    min-width: 300px;
  }
}
```

The div horizontal-3 is not centering when the screen is smaller than 720px. Float is on none and the margins are set to zero, display is block as well. Why is it not centering?

Comment: could you make it into a runnable snippet so it’s easier for us to test?

Answer (score 1):

Most important, it's not `margin-left: 0 auto` and `margin-right: 0 auto`, but either just `margin: 0 auto` or `margin-left: auto` and `margin-right: auto`, i.e. either ONE value for the single parameters or combined values for the shorthand parameter. (see here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qrbNZZ)

Answer (score 1):

Just make

```
.horizontal-3{
    margin: auto;
}
```

When you write `margin-right` it just mean you are giving margin from right, which is supposed to be a single value but you gave there **two** vaues `0 auto`. So just give `margin: auto` and everything will work fine.